# e.pageX is not working properly in all resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

onClick a span, I have to display a message in that position. So I have used e.pageX to determine the mouse click position, since there may be more than two spans. It works fine in a resolution. If I maximizes the resolution then the message is displaying far away from the clicked span.

```
$('div.moveRemoveItems').on('click','.detailRowThree #itemRawHerb',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#viewboxCR').css( 'left', e.pageX+30 );
    $('div#viewboxCR').show();
    $('div#viewboxCR').css('z-index','999');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to set css property in this html model:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

so the css property should be

```
.parent{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.child{
position: relative;
width: 200px;
margin: auto;
}
```

So it should work. Nevertheless you can use jquery method .resize(), somthing like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    // your diffirent code here for calcaulating parametrs 
});
```

If I right understood you.

Comment: I am not using parent -> child model.

div#viewboxCR is a div which has to display onClick the span at the clicked position.